# Java: initialized inline private final field is null

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I cannot understand why a private variable is null even if it's initialized inline. Here a snippet of my code:

```
public abstract class A {
    public A() {
        initialize();
    }

    protected abstract void initializeLayout();
    protected void initialize() {
        // Do something
        initializeLayout();
    }
}

public abstract class B extends A {
    private final Object myVariable = new Object();

    @Override
    protected void initializeLayout() {
        // Do something with myVariable
    }
}
```

Well, when this code reaches B.initailizeLayout, myVariable is NULL. I thought inline field were initialized before everything else, even before constructor. Am I wrong with something?

Comment: What the heck is a `varType`? Just referring to as a place holder? So like any object?

Comment: Yeah, i'ts just a placeholder. I should have used something more appropriate probably even I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: just use `Object` as a placeholder

Comment: [Suggested reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5). And as a rule of thumb, invoking overrideable methods from a constructor is a VBI (Very Bad Idea).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The constructor of the super class A (which calls `initialize()` which calls `B`'s `initializeLayout()`) is executed before the instance variables of the sub-class B are initialized. Therefore your instance variable `myVariable` is still null at that time.

Answer (score 2):

The (possibly implicit) constructor of the child B will do the following:

- have all fields zeroed (null, 0, 0.0, false)
- call the constructor of super A
- - call B.initializeLayout with all fields null
- initialize all fields that are assigned to in their declaration
- call the rest of the constructor

So what you are attempting are doing is very error prone in java.
Many style checkers mark this code as bad style (**calling non-final method in constructor**).

You may do

```
private /*final*/ Object myVariable; // Must not be initialized!

@Override
protected void initializeLayout() {
    myVariable = new Object();
    // Do something with myVariable
}
```

Having myVariable initialized would initialize myVariable after the call to initializeLayout.

Better to avoid.

Comment: nice, I like the reasoning you gave to avoid this kind of pattern. But what it has to with the words **calling non-final method in constructor** ? can you elaborate that portion or provide some useful links.

Comment: @rajuGT A base class cannot call a child class method that isn't declared on the base class, therefore any methods called from the constructor must be declared on the base class. Any `final` base class method cannot be overridden by the child class, so the base class implementation will be used (safely, because the base class' members are initialized before the constructor is called). Inversely, any method which is not `final` could be overridden by the child and is therefore subject to this danger. Thus, non-`final` methods are not (necessarily) safe to call from the constructor.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure said it. Calling a final (= non overridable) method like a private method is safe (if itself does not call any overridable). Hence if one calls a setter in a constructor better make it final.

Comment: Thank you both, very clear explanation. :)